# NTP does not syncronize with debian 9.7 and hence date and time are not correct

Tags: debian, ntp, ntpd

setup:
 Client - Debian 9.7
 Server - Windows 10 with "Absolute Time server" application running for synchronization

Sharing below details

1. NTP deamon process gets started on Debian 9.7 client
2. Request has been sent from client to NTP server
3. NTP Server transmits the updated time and date response (Confirmed via wireshark and tcpdump) and is received at N/w interface level of client
4. Linux (date) is not able to update the time and date

```
ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 192.168.6.35    .INIT.          16 u  147  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000

ntpq> associations
ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 54745  8011   yes    no  none    reject    mobilize  1
```

With the same setup by having Debian 8.6 client NTP Functions perfectly fine

Comment: have you checked/opened the firewall ports on the server machine?

Comment: yes..port =123 is used by the NTP and its opened for UDP and TCP communication.Also firewall is disabled.